# eb cli error message Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I tried to install eb cli throw pip or msi and i always get the same wierd message after i check if eb was installed successfully:

> PS C:\Users\liron> eb --version
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\liron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 570, in _build_master
>       ws.require(**requires**)
>     File "C:\Users\liron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 888, in require
>       needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
>     File "C:\Users\liron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 779, in resolve
>       raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
>   pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (colorama 0.3.9 (c:\users\liron\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages), Requirement.parse('colorama==0.3.7'), {'awsebcli'})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\liron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\eb-script.py", line 6, in 
>       from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
>     File "C:\Users\liron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 3095, in 
>       @_call_aside
>     File "C:\Users\liron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 3079, in _call_aside
>       f(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\liron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
>       working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
>     File "C:\Users\liron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 572, in _build_master
>       return cls._build_from_requirements(**requires**)
>     File "C:\Users\liron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 585, in _build_from_requirements
>       dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
>     File "C:\Users\liron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 779, in resolve
>       raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
>   pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (colorama 0.3.7 (c:\users\liron\appdata\roaming\python\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('colorama<0.4,>=0.3.9; sys_platform == "win32"'), {'docker-compose'})

i tried to install with pip and msi.

- aws version: aws-cli/1.15.35 Python/3.6.0 Windows/7 botocore/1.10.35
- python version: Python 3.6.3
- pip version: pip 10.0.1 from c:\users\liron\appdata\roaming\python\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6).

i tried to update and uninstall everything without any luck.
thank you for your help :)

Comment: This issue seems to address your problem: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2610 . Have you seen it?

Comment: Ugrading to awsebcli 3.14.1 should fix this problem for you -- `pip install awsebcli==3.14.1`

Comment: Tyvm progfan, i tried to solve it with so many versions and finally it worked, ty for the help! -- pip install awsebcli==3.14.1

Comment: For some reason, 3.14.1 didn't work for me when I called `eb deploy`. I had to use `pip install awsebcli==3.13.0`